# PHP Image Generation

Tags: php, image

So, for a simple test game, I'm working on generating user images based on their current in-game avatar. I got this idea from Club Penguin and GTA V. They both generate images of the current in-game avatar.

I created a script to simply put a few images together and print out the final image to the client. It's similar to how Club Penguin does it, I believe: http://cdn.avatar.clubpenguin.com/%7B13bcb2a5-2e21-442c-b8e4-10516be6abc6%7D/cp?size=300

As you can see, the penguin is wearing multiple clothing items. The items are each different images located at http://mobcdn.clubpenguin.com/game/items/images/paper/image/300/ (ex: http://mobcdn.clubpenguin.com/game/items/images/paper/image/300/210.png)

Anyway, I've already made the script and all, but I have a few questions.

When going to Club Penguin's or Grand Theft Auto's avatar generator, you'll notice it finishes the request so fast. Even when it's a new user, (so before it has a chance to cache the image since it hasn't been generated yet), it finishes in under a second.

How could I possibly speed up the image generation process? Right now I'm just using PHP, but I could definitely switch over to another language. I know a few others too and I'm willing to learn. Which language can provide the fastest web-image generator (it has to connect to a database first to grab the user avatar info)?

For server specs, how much RAM and all that fun stuff would be an okay amount? Right now I'm using an [OVH cloud server](http://www.ovh.com/us/vps/vps-cloud.xml) (VPS Cloud 2) to test it and it's fine and all. But, if someone with experience with this could help, what might happen if I started getting a lot more traffic and there were people with 100+ image requests being made per client when they first log in (relationship system that shows their friend's avatar). I'll probably use Cloudflare and other caching tools to help so that most of them get cached for a maximum of 24 hours, but I can't completely rely on that.

tl;dr:
Two main questions:

1. What's the fastest way to generate avatars on the web (right now I'm using PHP)?
2. What are some good server specs for around 100+ daily unique clients (at minimum) using this server for generating these avatars?

Edit: Another question, which webserver could process more requests for this? Right now I'm using Apache for this server, but my other servers are using nginx for other API things (like logging users in, getting info, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IMHO, language is not the bottleneck. PHP is fast enough for real-time small images processing. You just need right algorithm. Also, check out bytecode caching engines such as APC, or XCache, or even HHVM. They can significantly improve PHP performance.
2. I think, any VPS can do the job until you have >20 concurrent requests. The more clients use service **at the same time** the more RAM you need. You can easily determine your script memory needs and other performance info by using profiler, such as [XHProf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php).
3. Nginx or Lighttpd in FastCGI mode use less RAM than Apache http server and they can handle more concurrent connections. But is's not important until you have many concurrent connections.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes, PHP is can do this job fast and flexible(example generate.php?size=32)
2. I know only German webspaces, but they have also an English interface. [www.nitrado.net](http://www.nitrado.net)